# Can't connect my admin router page

Tags: router

Today I woke up with an unconfigured router, and I know to configure it, however I can not access 192.168.1.1, the administration page, i just cant! And i do not know why!

This message is showing in the browser 'Unable to connect to the Internet'.

I already search throw several forums, ask in fb communities, no one knows how to solve my problem. I'm seriously considering buying another router.

This is my router and my configs:

[image]

I already try:

```
http://www.routerlogin.net
https://www.routerlogin.net
192.168.1.1
192.168.0.1
192.168.1.0
192.168.0.0
```

Router name: netgear wnr1000.

I already reset the router also and i am using a Mac Book Pro.

Please, if someone knows how to solve this, please help me! I do home office and i need the internet tomorrow...

Comment: Did you check your network cable (Computer -> Router)?

Comment: Yes, everything working @Nikolay

Answer (score 4):

Change your IP assignment from "manual" to "automatic". Then reboot/refresh your network card. You should now be able to connect and configure router.

Your issue is that your IP address (as per your screenshot) is `201.87.153.166` which can't connect to your router.

Change to DHCP, get a DHCP-assigned IP address, then check your settings for your gateway and try accessing the IP of your gateway (router in your case) in your browser.

Comment: i don't know why, but i can't assign an automatic ip @Kristian

Comment: In your screenshot, there's a dropdownlist that says "manualmente", change that to "automatic" (or whatever appropriate translation).

Comment: the only options there is Using DHCP, using DHCP with manual address, using BootP and create pppoe service @Kristian

Comment: DHCP (not with manual address) is what you need. That will give you an automatic (also known as dynamic) IP address, which should allow you to connect. If it doesn't set your IP to 192.168.1.100 - subnet to 255.255.255.0 and gateway 192.168.1.1  those settings should also allow you to connect if your routers IP is indeed 192.168.1.1 otherwise try resetting the router to factory settings.

Comment: i did that, and seems to work the automatically ip, but when i try access the 192.168.1.1 the page doesn't load -> http://s28.postimg.org/ec5wdmcc9/Captura_de_Tela_2015_02_05_s_23_00_22.jpg?noCache=1423184666 ... looks like a looping, just connecting

Comment: what is your new IP address? the router will probably be on .1 or .254 on the network your host is now on. check your current IP address to find the network.

Comment: the quickstart guide for your router( http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNR1000V4/Generic_N150_N300_Wireless_Router_QSG_Color_08Aug2014.pdf) says go to go to www.routerlogin.net to configure the router. 
That implies that it will intercept DNS queries for its management interface. make sure its restored to factory, and then try to go to that page. Default login is `admin` `password`.

Comment: @MrBearAndBeeryour the picture you posted in a comment is very small. It's really hard to see anything. Can you provide a larger image?